# What's equivalent of SelectedValuePath property in Windows phone's listpicker

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8, enums, listpicker

I am creating a Windows Phone app. I actually want to bind `enum` to `ListPicker`. Somehow I managed to get dictionary of type `Dictionary<Enum, string>`. Now I want to set `ItemSource` of `ListPicker` with that dictionary. It has `DisplayMemberPath` property but I can't find `SelectedValuePath`, how can I use that?